# Python -- attributes inexplicably changing with nothing in between changing them?

Tags: python, attributes, wxpython

I can't figure out how this is happening, here's the relevant code in a class:

```
    def flip_states(self, newValue):
        ...
        self.currentState = newValue
        self.currenStateStr = genConfig.SENSOR_STATE_TO_STR[newValue]
        self.update_field_in_db("currentState", self.currentState)
        self.update_field_in_db("currentStateStr", self.currenStateStr)
        wx.CallAfter(dispatcher.send, eventConfig.ELEMENT_STATE_LISTENER, 
           orders=[self.genType, self.currentStateStr, self.name, self.id])
```

Simple enough, but the update_field_in_db calls gets the newly reassigned version of self.currentStateStr, but the wx.CallAfter call gets the old value of self.currentStateStr

When I put a print of the currentStateStr value received from the db call, it is correct and the db updates as expected -- then I put a print in this function right after the db calls but before the wx.CallAfter, they are back to what they were.

I thought maybe this had something to do with how Python assigned lists, but I can print the attributes without a list and they are still the old ones.  I've scoured the db call to make sure nothing else is occurring to change them.  Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

EDIT 1:

update_field_in_db is this:

```
def update_field_in_db(self, updateCol, updateTarget):
        self.database.update_element(updateCol=updateCol, updateTarget=updateTarget, **self.dbArgs)
```

and then database.update_element is:

```
def update_element(self, elementType, updateCol, updateTarget, whereCol, whereTarget, updateAll=False):
        self.open_cursor()
        if not updateAll:
            addQuotes1 = "'" if type(updateTarget).__name__ == "str" else ""
            addQuotes2 = "'" if type(whereTarget).__name__ == "str" else ""
            query = "UPDATE " + genConfig.DB_TABLES[elementType] + " SET {0} = {add1}{1}{add1} WHERE {2} = {add2}{3}{add2}"
            self.execute_query(query.format(updateCol, updateTarget, whereCol, whereTarget, add1=addQuotes1, add2=addQuotes2))
        else:
            pass # Not Implemented Yet
        self.close_cursor()
```

Comment: What does `update_field_in_db` look like?

Comment: Can't see your problem, but `type(updateTarget).__name__ == "str"` is horrible. You mean `isinstance(updateTarget, str)`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'm still learning.

Comment: what heappens if you add a print statement before `wx.CallAfter`? do you get the old value or the new value

Comment: Okay, I figured it out -- I'm an idiot.  Look closely, I assign "curren"StateStr instead of "current" -- I missed the "t" in the assignment and the db calls, but I didn't miss it in the callafter call.

Answer (score 0):

currentStateStr is spelled without the t in the assignment and DB call, it is spelled with the t in the wx.CallAfter call.

Just a spelling error, but a tough to see one -- Eclipse highlighting all same-named variables finally revealed it.